# Table last cells to be aligned right

Tags: html, css

I have a table with html as follows:

```
<div id="cart">
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Product Name</th>
<th >Price</th>
<th>Qty</th>
<th >Options</th>
<th >Value</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<tr>
<td class="item-pid">5</td>
<td class="item-name"></td>
<td class="item-price"></td>
<td class="item-quantity">1</td>
<td class="options">color</td>
<td class="item-total">$23.52</td>
</tr>
<tr>

<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<th>Sub-Total</td>
<td class="third">5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<th>Shipping Option</td>    
<td class="third">EMS</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<th>Grand Total</td>    
<td class="third">100</td>
</tr>

<CAPTION ALIGN="bottom">
This is the table's bottom caption
</CAPTION>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

I need the last three row columns Sub-total, shipping option and grand total to be as a standalone single column with all td 's prior to it removed. currently i am adding:

```
<td><td><td><td>
```

to align it to right. All prior cells are displaying blank. **I want all those cells removed and the last 3 cells aligned to right.**

How is that possible?

I have a [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shels123/Xm6n2/) here..

Help Requested. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change those 3 rows code into this:

```
<tr>
<td colspan="5" style="text-align:right;">Sub-Total</td>
<td class="third">5</td>
</tr> 
<tr>
<td colspan="5" style="text-align:right;">Shipping Option</td>  
<td class="third">EMS</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="5" style="text-align:right;">Grand Total</td>  
<td class="third">100</td>
</tr>
```

You can use `colspan` to merge the colums and `text-align:right` for the text to align right.

Check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xm6n2/1/)..

Comment: Thank you..What if i need to remove the Sub-Total,Shipping Option and Grand Total cell and just display label only??

Comment: What do you mean by label only ?? I think Sub-Total,Shipping Option and Grand Total is the label..

Comment: No problem..I was just asking whether label can be displayed outside the td in which it is displayed (without td). Thank you for your help.

Comment: It can, but you need to change so a lot of things from your previous code.. I prefer removing the border and background-color, if you want..